# отсутствуют имена функция в выводе gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, stacktrace

Использую данную функция для вывода stacktrace

```
   void print_trace()
   {
   char pid_buf[30];
   sprintf(pid_buf, "%d", getpid());
   char name_buf[512];
   name_buf[readlink("/proc/self/exe", name_buf, 511)]=0;
   int child_pid = fork();
   if (!child_pid) {
        dup2(2,1); // redirect output to stderr
        fprintf(stdout,"stack trace for %s pid=%s\n",name_buf,pid_buf);
        execlp("gdb", "gdb", "--batch", "-n", "-ex", "thread", "-ex", "bt", 
   name_buf, pid_buf, NULL);
        abort(); /* If gdb failed to start */
   } else {
        waitpid(child_pid,NULL,0);
   }
   }
```

При сработке сигнала на выводе получаю:

```
*** Error in `/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv': free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x00007fd7e408b8b0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7277f)[0x7fd7f1e1277f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x78026)[0x7fd7f1e18026]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x78d53)[0x7fd7f1e18d53]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x9fccf)[0x7fd7f2f31ccf]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5(_Z17qt_message_output9QtMsgTypeRK18QMessageLogContextRK7QString+0x9e)[0x7fd7f2f2e21e]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN6QDebugD2Ev+0x60)[0x7fd7f301e640]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x424650]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x44ea8a]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x454d08]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x453fbd]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x4537ac]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x452623]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x4449ee]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x445eb3]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x4449ee]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x44681e]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x446505]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x446a93]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x46d99b]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x4701a2]
/usr/mon/nav/mon_recv[0x46ee64]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5(+0xad72e)[0x7fd7f2f3f72e]
/usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5(+0xb07f9)[0x7fd7f2f427f9]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x80a4)[0x7fd7f29ec0a4]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fd7f1e8502d]
```

mon_recv мое приложение,работает на удаленном сервере, как мне сделать что бы видно было читабельные имена функций, может надо исходники где то рядом положить?

---

Добавил ключи, все равно нет имен.
Параметры сборки: g++ -c -pipe -ggdb -std=c++11 -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB

Comment: Следует пересобрать его с отладочной информацией (опция `-g`, `-ggdb` и без `-s`).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: к проблеме не относится, но советую советую посмотреть в сторону `backtrace (3)` — не нужно будет за собой gdb таскать...

Comment: Полученное решение проблемы лучше изложить в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заработало после добавления ключа -rdynamic линкеру.